# Cofinality assuming GCH

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

There is this statement that GCH holds iff any pair of regular cardinals $\kappa,\lambda$ such that $\kappa<\lambda$ satisfy that $\lambda^\kappa = \lambda$.

Assume we do have two such cardinals. Take the sequence $\langle\lambda^\xi\mid \xi<\kappa\rangle$, then it seems that $\lim_{\xi\to\kappa} \lambda^\xi = \lambda^\kappa = \lambda$ and so $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda) \le \kappa < \lambda$ contradicting regularity.

I am obviously missing something, but I have no idea what, because if my reasoning is correct it seems that under these hypotheses there could not be two different regular cardinals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, it seems that I jumped the shark assuming that exponentiation is monotone in the exponent. So that kinda answers my own questions.

Comment: Now I see the dire consequences of not teaching you better LaTeX last year.

Comment: What you are assuming is not monotonicity but continuity and, indeed, exponentiation is not necessarily continuous. For example, we can have $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$ for all $n$, and yet $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ is always larger that $\aleph_{\omega}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that under the working assumption, $\lambda^\xi=\lambda$. So the sequence is constant. Therefore the cofinality of $\lambda$ is not $\kappa$ or less, because that would require a sequence of cardinals *smaller* than $\lambda$ itself.